# How do I contain feGaussianBlur within a circle?

Tags: svg

I'm trying to contain a feGaussianBlur within a circle in order make the circle's gradient smoother, but the blur expands beyond the circle.

I'm also using another gradient with a feGaussianBlur behind the top circle that will expand beyond it, so I can't use a mask over the top circle to cover up the color bleeding beyond it, else the blur of the circle below it will also be covered.

[image]

Comment: Blurring linear gradient produces another or same linear gradient. It only makes sense if initial gradient has multiple color stops arranged not linearly and probably it's not worth it. Also, how is it - "make gradient smoother"? It's already as smooth as it can be. If you are not happy with the way color transition is going, you probably should try adding some custom stops

Comment: The "Contained Blur" isn't actually blurred, and the "Uncontained Blur" also isn't a blurred gradient since the design software I used to illustrate what I meant doesn't allow for these effects. It's just used to visually illustrate the gist of what I typed. The gradients I'm using have many colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I add a gradient to two circles and a rectangle.
The rectangle is made into a circle using a clip-path.
The second circle and the rectangle has the filter applied.
The filter has the feComposite/in to keep the filter inside the circle as suggested by [Michael Mullany](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71815292/322084): `<feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>`

As I see it the the one without filter looks more smooth. So, I don't know if it makes sense -- maybe in your use case?

```html
<svg width="500" viewBox="0 0 300 110" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="blue" />
      <stop offset="30%" stop-color="blue" />
      <stop offset="70%" stop-color="lightblue" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="lightblue" />
    </linearGradient>
    <clipPath id="cp1">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" />  
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#gradient)" />
  <text font-size="10" x="50" y="105" text-anchor="middle">circle no filter</text>
  
  <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#gradient)" filter="url(#blur)" />
  <text font-size="10" x="150" y="105" text-anchor="middle">circle filter</text>
  
  <rect transform="translate(200 0)" width="100" height="100" fill="url(#gradient)" clip-path="url(#cp1)" filter="url(#blur)"/>
  <text font-size="10" x="250" y="105" text-anchor="middle">rect filter</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

To contain a blur to the area of the original graphic, you add a feComposite/in to the end of your filter.

```
<feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
```